# Rancher use self-hosted and cloud provider?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

Do I understand that right:

1. Rancher is an abstraction from Kubernetes.
2. With Rancher, you can self-host a Kubernetes cluster and use also cloud providers like aws, google... at the same time.

If 2. is right is it possible to split the load between self-hosted Kubernetes cluster and cloud provider Kubernetes clusters?

Is it also possible to prior the self-hosted, if the resources from the self-hosted cluster are exhausted then use the cloud providers cluster and expand the cluster with the cluster autoscaler?

Answer (score 0):

A simple definition would be to call Rancher as a manager and provisioner of kubernetes clusters.

Rancher can manage self hosted and cloud provider kubernetes cluster. Those two cluster are independent of each other. Load cannot be shared or balanced across them.